# Android POST Request 400 Response code throws Exception

Tags: java, android, post, http-status-code-400

When i send a POST Request to a Server, if the response is 200 i get the JSON body. However for unsuccessful requests the servers send a 400 response code but my android code throws a FileNotFoundException. Is there any difference between reading a 400 response and a 200 response ?

```
        StringBuffer responseBuilder = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    try
    {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(requestURL).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(NetworkConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setReadTimeout(NetworkConstants.SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

        out = conn.getOutputStream();
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
        String s = formatParams();
        Log.d("-------------------------------------------------->", s);
        writer.write(s);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    finally
    {
        if (out != null)
        {
            try
            {
                out.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
    try
    {
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            responseBuilder.append(line);
            if (!rd.ready())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    String response = responseBuilder.toString();
    Log.d("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", response);
    return response;
```

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response code isn't 200 or 2xx, use getErrorStream() instead of getInputStream() to parse the json and show the message provided by your backend.

Comment: so the server sends me information with the 400 response code. How can i read that ?

Comment: it's pretty basic stuff mate, just check the response code when you make your connection and handle the response yourself. For example if you end up with anything but 200 you should display a message of some sort for the user and don't continue trying to read the response.

Comment: our server is designed in such a way that if the request params are incorrect, say the user provides a wrong username or password a 400 response code is generated. In this case the server sends the json response with the error message that is generated. So i have to read the response in this case as well. How can i do this ?

Comment: Yes, instead of reading the InputStream you parse the json provided in the ErrorStream (getErrorStream())

Answer (score 5):

Use `getErrorStream()` for this. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

> If the HTTP response indicates that an error occurred, `getInputStream()` will throw an `IOException`. Use `getErrorStream()` to read the error response. The headers can be read in the normal way using `getHeaderFields()`.

Sample code:

```
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode >= 400 && responseCode <= 499) {
            Log.e(TAG, "HTTPx Response: " + responseCode + " - " + httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage());
            in = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getErrorStream());
        }
        else {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            urlResponse.append(line);
        }
```

Comment: Great answer +1 for `httpURLConnection.getErrorStream()` as it helps to read error contents in response...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since the question was asked but for the benefit of other people who are still having this kind of problem please note that another possible cause of the problem is using "connection.getContent()" to get InputStream. 
 like so:

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) connection.getContent();
```

this can create a problematic situation where response code larger than 399 will not be processed at all.
so the recommendation is to work directly with getInputStream() and getErrorStream() as shown in previous comments and as in the following example:

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        String urlString = "http://www.someurl.com";
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream is;
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
            is = connection.getInputStream();
        } else {
            is = connection.getErrorStream();
        }

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String tempLine;
        while ((tempLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(tempLine);
        }
        String serverResponse = response.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```